# Please help me writing the test Class for Aggregate function and Charts

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Using below code im generating the Chart on VF page, I'm unable to write test Class for the below code:

```
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {  
        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();  
        dftlyuser = new List<dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_User__c >();
        String userobject= 'dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_User__c';
        String [] userobjectFields= new String [] {'Id','Name'};
            if(isAccessibleFLSpermession(userobject,userobjectFields) && Schema.sObjectType.dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_User__c.isAccessible()){
                dftlyuser  = [select Id,Name from dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_User__c where dftlytime__User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1 ];
                if(dftlyuser.size() == 1 && dftlyuser[0].Id != null){
                     dftlyUserid = dftlyuser[0].Id;
                     String tdetailobject= 'dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c';
                     String [] tdetailobjectFields= new String [] {'createddate','dftlytime__Time_Worked__c'};
                     if(isAccessibleFLSpermession(tdetailobject,tdetailobjectFields) && Schema.sObjectType.dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c.isAccessible()){
                        List<aggregateResult> results = [Select Day_only(createddate) cd, sum(dftlytime__Time_Worked__c) total FROM dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c where createddate = THIS_WEEK and dftlytime__Time_Worked__c != null and dftlytime__dftlyTimesheetUser__c =:dftlyuser[0].Id GROUP BY Day_only(Createddate) ];
                        if(results.size() > 0){
                            for(AggregateResult ar :results ){           
                                data.add(new PieWedgeData(String.valueof(ar.get('cd')),Double.valueof(ar.get('total'))));
                            }
                            return data;
                         }
                         return data;
                     } 
                     return data;         
                }
                return data;
            }
            return data;
    }
```

and test function is as follows

```
@isTest 
      static void test() {
        dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c a = new dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c(name='abc');
        insert a ;
        Test.startTest();
        createCheckin ctrl = new createCheckin ();
        createCheckin.PieWedgeData[] data = ctrl.getPieData();
        Test.stopTest();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running your tests as a System Administrator, I assume `isAccessibleFLSpermession` will return true.

You will need to insert a `dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_User__c` object in your test as well as the `dftlytime__dftly_Timesheet_Detail__c` object you are already inserting; you should set a `dftlytime__Time_Worked__c` field value in that object too. Also add an assert of the size and then of the values of the `data` local variable.